# INSERT query in a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to put INSERT query in a function and I come up with these:

```
function qry_insert($table, $data, $ignore = false)
    {
        $qry = array();
        if (is_array($qry) === true)
        {
            $qry['query'] = 'INSERT ';
            if ($ignore === true)
            {
                $qry['query'] .= 'IGNORE ';
            }

            foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            {
                $data[$key] = $key . ' = ' . $value;
            }

            $qry['query'] .= 'INTO ' . $table . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $data);
        }
        return implode('', $qry);
}
```

I'm calling this function using this:

```
$data = array(
    'username'=>'userTest',
    'email'=>'emailTest', 
    'password'=>'passwordTest'
);

qry_insert('users',$data);
```

My problem is, I'm not getting errors and there's no inserted item. I tried every thing but I still get no inserted item. My configs and database settings are correct because when use the line below it's working.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,..) VALUES ('userTest'...)");
```

What seems to be my error?  Is there any short code/function to do this?

Comment: Tried `mysql_query("..") or die(mysql_error());` ?

Comment: Please debug your query string via echo statement

Comment: Quote the strings user=userTest -> user='userTest'.  $data[$key] = $key . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value). "'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually inserting anything with this code, you still need to do some sort of mysqli_insert/query efter your call to qry_insert. My guess is that Code Igniter has some class to handle this.

Edit:

See [this post](http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/inserting-data-into-database-in-codeigniter-t2007.html) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it!

```
function qry_insert($table, $data){

    $fields = array_keys( $data );  
    $values = array_map( "mysql_real_escape_string", array_values( $data ) );
    mysql_query( "INSERT INTO $table(".implode(",",$fields).") VALUES ('".implode("','", $values )."');") or die( mysql_error() );

}



$data = array(
    'username'  =>  'userTest',
    'email'     =>  'emailTest',
    'password'  =>  'passwordTest'
);

$qry = qry_insert('users',$data);
```

thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function produces a query that does not include quotes around the string values. It outputs:

> INSERT INTO users SET username = userTest, email = emailTest, password = passwordTest

As you can see, it's missing quotes around `userTest`, `emailTest` and `passwordTest`, therefore this will cause the query to fail with a syntax error. Also, you will notice that this is the `UPDATE` style syntax not the [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) style.

It would be better to re-write your function using a prepared statement and using the correct [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax, instead of concatenating the values.

Comment: i tried this but it didn't help

$sql['query'] .= 'INTO ' . $table  . implode(', ', $data);

Comment: The proper insert syntax would be `INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES('userTest', 'emailTest', 'passwordTest')`. You haven't included the column list or the VALUES() container, or quotes.

Comment: UPDATE syntax is fine for mysql and can be used to create insert, update and select queries using the same code

Answer (score 0):

You are actually generating sql query with this function call, you need to use `mysql_query` to insert data into table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PDO instead?  It basically does what you're trying to do with that function but all wrapped up in PHP functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php